# Using ffmpeg native aac codec, but metadata says libvo_aacenc, and faststart not supported?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg and am trying to switch from using the 'libvo_aacenc' encoder to the native aac encoder.  It seems to work, but the metadata in the output seems to indicate that it's still using the old encoder.

I changed the audio portion of my ffmpeg call from

-i out.wav -acodec libvo_aacenc

to

-i out.wav -acodec aac -strict experimental

But the output includes this:

Metadata:

```
encoder         : Lavf53.21.1

Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 432x256, q=-1--1, 30 tbn, 30 tbc

Stream #0.1: Audio: libvo_aacenc, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 200 kb/s
```

I don't understand where it is still getting the 'libvo_aacenc' from?

Another problem, maybe unrelated, is that when I try to add the "-movflags +faststart" option to my call, I get errors:

[mp4 muxer @ 0x49ad520] [Eval @ 0x3e59d37c6b0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'faststart'
[mp4 muxer @ 0x49ad520] Unable to parse option value "faststart"
[mp4 muxer @ 0x49ad520] Error setting option movflags to value +faststart.

From looking online it would appear my ffmpeg version is old, pre faststart, but my ffmpeg version is 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers built on Mar 16 2015 13:26:50 with gcc 4.6.3

That seems like it should include faststart, which was introduced in 2013, right?
Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks very much,

Bob

Comment: You need to upgrade to a recent version. The native AAC encoder became stable only in Dec 2015.

Comment: ok,thanks -- any idea why my metadata would still say libvo_aacenc?